# Login with LinkedIn Api using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, oauth, linkedin-api

**I am trying to login with linkedin api using codeigniter.My code is like this.**

**Controller**

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
    function index()
    {
        echo anchor('user/login', 'Sign in with Linkedin');
    }
    function login()
    {
        $data['api_key'] = "xxxxxxxx";
        $data['api_secret'] = "xxxxxxx";
        $data['callback_url'] = base_url()."user/login";
       $this->load->library("LinkedIn",$data);
       //echo $data['callback_url'];
       $linked = new LinkedIn($data);
       $url = urldecode($linked->getLoginUrl(
        array(
    LinkedIn::SCOPE_BASIC_PROFILE, 
    LinkedIn::SCOPE_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
  )
       ));   
       //echo $url;
       if(isset($_GET['code']))
       {
        $code = $_GET['code'];
        $access_token = $linked->getAccessToken($code);
        $token_expires = $linked->getAccessTokenExpiration();
        $linked->setAccessToken($access_token);
        //$user=$linked->get('v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)','get',$access_token);
       //$info = $linked->get('/people/~:(first-name,last-name,company,positions)');
        $profile_fileds = array(
            'id',
            'firstName',
            'maiden-name',
            'lastName',
            'picture-url',
            'email-address',
            'location:(country:(code))',
            'industry',
            'summary',
            'specialties',
            'interests',
            'public-profile-url',
            'last-modified-timestamp',
            'num-recommenders',
            'date-of-birth',
        );
        $profileData = $linked->get('/people/~:(' . implode(',', $profile_fileds) . ')');
        var_dump($profileData);
       }
       else
       {
            redirect($url);
       }
    }
    function cancel()
    {
        echo "canecl by user";
    }

}
```

The first time my code worked correctly but when i refresh the page it give me an errror like that

> Type: RuntimeException
>   Message: Access Token Request Error: invalid_request -- missing required >parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : >Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match >authorization code or authorization code expired

Answer (score 0):

I have done it,add access_token in session like that.

```
if($this->session->userdata('token))
{
$linked->setaccesstoken($this->session->userdata('token));
}
else{
/////same codepaste here
}
```